# Encoding problem when I want to save a CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I want to save this list in a CSV file in Python.

```py
row = ['4CIIN', '04-11-2022', '00:00', '2022-11-05 00:00:00', '00:00', b'4CIIN Compiti Scrivi un programma C che, 3CIIN letto l\xe2\x80\x99anno di nascita di una persona e l\xe2\x80\x99anno attuale in input, calcoli l\xe2\x80\x99et\xc3\xa0 della persona. Restituisci un opportuno messaggio se la persona \xc3\xa8 maggiorenne o no.   - From Google', '0']
```

With this code:

```
with open('salva.csv','w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    write=csv.writer(f)
    write.writerows(row)
```

My result seems not correct

```
4,C,I,I,N
0,4,-,1,1,-,2,0,2,2
0,0,:,0,0
2,0,2,2,-,1,1,-,0,5, ,0,0,:,0,0,:,0,0
0,0,:,0,0
52,67,73,73,78,32,67,111,109,112,105,116,105,32,83,99,114,105,118,105,32,117,110,32,112,114,111,103,114,97,109,109,97,32,67,32,99,104,101,44,32,51,67,73,73,78,32,108,101,116,116,111,32,108,226,128,153,97,110,110,111,32,100,105,32,110,97,115,99,105,116,97,32,100,105,32,117,110,97,32,112,101,114,115,111,110,97,32,101,32,108,226,128,153,97,110,110,111,32,97,116,116,117,97,108,101,32,105,110,32,105,110,112,117,116,44,32,99,97,108,99,111,108,105,32,108,226,128,153,101,116,195,160,32,100,101,108,108,97,32,112,101,114,115,111,110,97,46,32,82,101,115,116,105,116,117,105,115,99,105,32,117,110,32,111,112,112,111,114,116,117,110,111,32,109,101,115,115,97,103,103,105,111,32,115,101,32,108,97,32,112,101,114,115,111,110,97,32,195,168,32,109,97,103,103,105,111,114,101,110,110,101,32,111,32,110,111,46,32,32,32,45,32,70,114,111,109,32,71,111,111,103,108,101
0
```

I need some basics to how convert the string in a correct way, and add the delimiter.

Comment: Your list has a mix of strings and byte-strings...

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, use `writerow` for a single list, not `writerows`.

Comment: What seems incorrect about your results? What different output or format are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to first convert any `bytes` into utf-8. Then use `.writerow()` to write a single row.

When using a `csv.writer()` you should use `newline=''` to avoid extra unwanted newlines ([this is explained in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv%20writer#csv.writer)).

For example:

```py
import csv

row = ['4CIIN', '04-11-2022', '00:00', '2022-11-05 00:00:00', '00:00', b'4CIIN Compiti Scrivi un programma C che, 3CIIN letto l\xe2\x80\x99anno di nascita di una persona e l\xe2\x80\x99anno attuale in input, calcoli l\xe2\x80\x99et\xc3\xa0 della persona. Restituisci un opportuno messaggio se la persona \xc3\xa8 maggiorenne o no.   - From Google', '0']
row_str = [v.decode('utf-8') if type(v) == bytes else v for v in row]

with open('salva.csv','w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    csv_output =  csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(row_str)
```

Giving you a single row with:

```
4CIIN,04-11-2022,00:00,2022-11-05 00:00:00,00:00,"4CIIN Compiti Scrivi un programma C che, 3CIIN letto l’anno di nascita di una persona e l’anno attuale in input, calcoli l’età della persona. Restituisci un opportuno messaggio se la persona è maggiorenne o no.   - From Google",0
```

Note: you will need to use an application that can correctly display utf-8 encodings to see this correctly.

Your code used `.writerows()`. This would try to iterate over each entry in your list and create a row for each. For example, it is iterating over your `4CIIN` string as separate characters which is why you see individual letters in your output.